# Analytics track event goal with unique value

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up an goal in analytics with this parameters:

```
Target type: Event
Category (matching): form
Action (matching): test
Label (matching): sent
Value: nothing
```

And i have this anlytics push:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'form', 'test', 'sent', '*dynamic_URI*']);
</script>
```

Is this going to work? Will the *dynamic_URI* be registered?

Answer (score 0):

from https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide:

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value, opt_noninteraction)    

value (optional)
An integer that you can use to provide numerical data about the user event.
```

So you can't pass a url as the fourth ("value") parameter.

As far as I know the value parameter was meant to help with adwords ROI calculation (to assign a $$ value to non-E-Commerce-events).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer! :)

I made som changes for my goals witch I hope will work.

```
Type: URL Destination
Goal URL: /form/test/*
Match type: Regular Expression Match
```

And my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/form/test/*dynamic_URI*']);
</script>
```